# Solving equation with floor

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it possible to solve for $i$ in the following equation?

EDIT- WolframAplha says it is possible but how do I do it?

> $$\left \lfloor{\displaystyle \frac n{2^i}}\right \rfloor =1  $$

I am not sure on how to separate the floor to solve for $i$

Comment: If $\floor{x}=1$ then $1≤x<2$. Then just solve the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ if and only if $1 \le x < 2$.  Thus you want
$2^i \le n < 2^{i+1}$.  Take base-$2$ logarithms of both sides, and you 
find $i = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

We can introduce a [slack variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable) $\epsilon$:
$$
1 = \lfloor n / 2^i \rfloor = n/2^i - \epsilon \quad (\epsilon \in [0,1))
$$
Then
$$
1 + \epsilon = n / 2^i \iff \\
2^i = n /(1+ \epsilon) \iff \\
i = \log_2(n/(1+\epsilon))
$$
This means
$$
\log_2(n/2) < i \le \log_2(n)
$$
You might want $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ as well (going by the name). Because we have
$$
\log_2(n) - \log_2(n/2) = \log_2(n/(n/2)) = \log_2(2) = 1
$$
we can now go reverse and have
$$
i = \log_2(n) - \epsilon' = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor \quad (\epsilon' \in [0,1))
$$